# Can I render single pass with cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, render-passes

I would like to render single passes in order to tweak some parameters like resolution or sample count. For example I would like to render a low sample count indirect light then denoise it and compose it back.
Or is there some way for me to change the sample count for different pass? I don't know if that just possible.

Comment: Yes.  Go to View Layer Properties in the properties editor and open the passes panel.  This will allow you to select which passes are rendered.

Comment: If you want different sample counts, render to .exr for both sample counts and then composite them together.

Comment: Thank you guys! But it seems that I cannot control light path just with view layer. But duplicate scene with linked copy seems to work for me.